# Wifi speeds gloriously inconsistent day to day, but very consistent hour to hour?

Tags: wireless-networking, troubleshooting, internet-speed, wireless-adapter

After several months of every experiment I can think to run, and just getting noisy data left and right, I'm out of ideas and cannot make this network's behavior fit within my grasp of physics.

Some nights I can stream from my desktop rig just fine (I need 3.5kbs up). Some nights I can't even push 0.5kbs up the pipe.  Some nights I start out fine, then 5PM rolls around and my stream starts dropping 60-70% frames. Some nights I have absolutely no difficulties.

Over the past few months I have controlled everything I can imagine contributing to this (most of these obviously don't change from session to session or even month to month but I figured I'd fiddle with them just to figure out what the hell), and have found no culprit.

If the speed was wildly inconsistent moment to moment I'd call it interference and be done with it, but it's not. It's more consistent than the Boston weather, in fact.

Here's what it's **NOT**:

1. Position of the wireless adapter (Linksys USB100 on a five-foot USB extension cable to get it away from the case and the metal desk.  - NOTE: Position doesn't have no effect, there's about a 50% difference in performance between the worst and best placement for the antenna.
2. The metal desk.
3. Channel
4. Frequency
5. Protocol
6. Time of day (though there is a slight tendency to be worse after 5PM, for the longest time I thought Twitch was throttling me, but when I started collecting data that hypo doesn't pass statistical testing).
7. Day of week (Though more of my bad days are on Fridays, see #6).
8. Weather conditions (although there is a marked tendency to be worse during wet weather, correlation is not causation, all theories of mechanism here have failed tests, and perfectly sunny weather can still experience brutal outages).
9. Room temperature
10. Uptime of any of the hardware I control
11. Whether or not the apartment above me is occupied
12. Whether or not my Air Conditioner is running.
13. My stream settings

Conditions: I live in a basement apartment (so the walls aren't great for radio signals), and the router is on the opposite end of the unit. My service over here sucks but when it works it's plenty good enough.  I'm running Windows 10, using a Linksys USB100 on a five-foot extension cable with cradle. I have a metal desk and steel boom for my mic.

I know I'm not going to get the full 200MBs my ISP promises me. I don't need to, that's not my question.

My question is: What else could be varying this slowly, resulting in such a severe swing in up/down speeds? I go from 20MBs down/4.5kbs up to 4MBs down/0.5kbs up (right now). This is true even if I deliberately control all factors except the passing of time.  What else can I test for?

Comment: 50kbs is more than 3.5kbps; Five foot USB extension is awful close to the length limits of certain revisions of USB

Comment: Reflex typo, fixing. Thanks for the catch

Comment: In order to eliminate WiFi has the problem can you simply run a long Ethernet cable to the machine? I realize it’s not a permanent solution, but it’s a cheap test, and eliminates all sort of factors

Comment: @Ramhound Yeah it's wifi. Ethernet is fine. Moreover it's **MY** wifi. My partner's lappy sat in my room happily chugs away at 40MBs down, 16MBs up...  My question is more about "Yes, my rig sucks, but if it sucks THAT badly why does it work at all? And if doesn't suck that badly, why does it suddenly crap out for hours and hours at a time?"

Comment: You have not controllled for a bad wifi adaptor or bad wifi driver.   My bet is you have a crappy realtek chipset based adaptor.

Comment: @davidgo Does the fact that it works more often than it doesn't not control for bad wifi adaptor? What could be wrong in a device with no moving parts that makes it go all but completely out for hours on end, and then reliably work just fine for days? (I'm gonna replace it anyway, but I'm just curious what fault you're suspecting)

Comment: Well it is WiFi 4 (or whatever 802.11g is) and WiFi 6 might make a difference but 5.0 is significantly hampered by walls (so that’s not a guarantee).  What might work is doing a mesh network and but connecting to one of the mesh devices by Ethernet. You don’t mention the WiFi specifications of the other device

Comment: I wouldnt think that is neccisarily so - for example it might have issues handling interference or handling MIMO or corrupting more bits causing compounding issues.  It may not be properly implementing the relevant standard which may only be apparent due to noise/traffic.

Comment: @davidgo I can accept that it's especially vulnerable to interference, but what sources of interference are so intermittent-but-also-slow-cycling?

Comment: Could be anything - including stuff not 802.11 related, the router selecting different frequencies which dont work so well for the client. Why not see if you can use an alternate driver?

Comment: @davidgo I did, it's got the most current, and nothing else I'm able to tweak about that has any effect. I didn't include it in the NOT list because I'm not technically competent enough to force out of date drivers on the thing.